# Designing model for a field in code first entity framework that is Null for certain drieved entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, code-first

I posted a slice of my data model over at programmers asking what the downside to my code was, and got some answers that yes there is a potential problem.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/258038/inheritance-is-a-null-property-in-the-parent-a-bad-practice

The bad practice is the `Amount` field. It returns `Null` to some entities, and the conclusion is that I should remove the `Amount` field from the parent class and use it in just the classes I need it in.

The way it is now using code first the data tables using the model below come out just the way I want them. The row fields look like:

```
Id, Title, Description, Amount, other fields
```

The `Amount` field on every entity seed to zero or `Null`, depending on rather or not the entity actually uses the field, and the indicator that a class uses the field is that the class must have the override for `Amount`.

What happens when I remove the virtual `Amount` in the `Navigation` class, and just place an `Amount` field in the classes were I actually store an amount, the table in the database looks like this:

```
Id, Title, Description, Amount, Amount1, Amount2, other fields
```

This is an undesirable result for many reasons.

The question is what can I do so I only have one `Amount` field in the data table?

```
public class Navigation
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    ObservableCollection<Navigation> Children { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal? Amount
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { value = null; }
    }
}

public class C1 : Navigation { }

public class C2 : Navigation { }

public class C3 : Navigation
{
    private decimal _amount;

    public override decimal? Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { if (value != null) _amount = (decimal)value; }
    }
}

public class C4 : Navigation
{
    private decimal _amount;

    public override decimal? Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { if (value != null) _amount = (decimal)value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not sure if it'll work though. What version of EF are you using?

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
    modelBuilder.Entity<C3>().Property(p => p.Amount).HasColumnName("Amount");
    modelBuilder.Entity<C4>().Property(p => p.Amount).HasColumnName("Amount");
 }
```

Comment: 6. + EF. Yeah I am thinking if there is a solution this is were it lay. I will give it a shot.

Comment: I woke up this morning with a solution, I thought I would try, before I tried it in the fluent api.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the inheritance. I removed the Amount field from Navigation. Made the Amount field in C3 virtual, and changed C4 to inherit from C3. Works fine.

```
public class Navigation
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    ObservableCollection<Navigation> Children { get; set; }

 //  public virtual decimal? Amount
 //   {
 //       get { return null; }
 //       set { value = null; }
 //   }
}

public class C1 : Navigation { }

public class C2 : Navigation { }

public class C3 : Navigation
{
    private decimal _amount;

    public virtual decimal? Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { if (value != null) _amount = (decimal)value; }
    }
}

public class C4 : C3
{
    private decimal _amount;

    public override decimal? Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { if (value != null) _amount = (decimal)value; }
    }
}
```